# Can't create new Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, project

I'm new to Xamarin Studio. I need to write a Forms app. When I try to create a new Solution I get to the point where I select "Forms App C#". I click the next button and in the following window I get to pick an app name but the next button remains grey. Do I miss something?[Screenshot for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTHqs.png)

Comment: it doesn't appear that all of the platform support was installed.  I would try re-running the universal installer and being sure that all of the Android and iOS bits are installed.

Comment: Even if I don't want to write Android or iOS apps?

Comment: XF on the Mac only supports Android and iOS.  What kind of projects do you want to create?

Comment: Something like in VS for Windows, so I get an executable file for Windows.

Comment: The you need to use Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure? I get executable files out of mono, why not from Xamarin Studio?

Comment: You can write console projects and windows forms with XS on a Mac.  But the tooling and libraries to do WPF, UWP, etc does not exist on the Mac.

Comment: [This table](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Development_Environments) in Xamarin docs shows which platforms can be built with different development tool & operating system combinations

Comment: Thx, I downloaded a VM installed Win10 and VS2015.